# Geofence Accuracy and Geofence method in indoor

Tags: win-universal-app

As I know that the geofence only supports for outdoor.
I had two questions ask about geofence below:
1. Any method that can use geofence in indoor?
2. What is the accuracy of geofence?

Answer (score 1):

For indoor I would suggest use beacons instead of geofence since is more suited for that case. Geofence accuracy is not that good even for small distance outdoors, is just good for larger distances at least more than 100 meters.